# Account team - 'Invalid cross reference id' when trying to add a member to the account team

Tags: profile, account-teams

We are currently experimenting some issues when we try to assign a user to an account team as a non-admin profile.

The error the end user gets is : '***insufficient access rights on cross-reference id***'.

Since we don't get this error as an administrator, we suspect this error to come from permissions and tried to investigate the following workarounds:

- Profile : No mention of the account teams ; the end-user has read/write permissions on account
- Sharing settings : Nothing related to account teams itself. The user has the read/write access on the record he owns

Assuming these issues, my questions are:

- Has anyone faced the same issue before ? What is the best workaround ?
- If you were to configure permissions on the account teams, how would you do it ?
- Any clues ?

Thanks in advance,

PS : We are on lightning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the OWD of account object. If it is very restrictive and if you are giving wider access through account team then the insert may fail.

Account team basically means you are operating on accountshare object so if you want to do account team update/insert though apex or data loader then you can do it directly on accountshare object.

Here is a article that talks about mass update/insert of account team members through data loader. May be this will help you.
[Mass Update Account team Through Data Loader](http://www.cloudforce4u.com/2013/06/account-team-mass-update-access-level.html)

Answer (score 3):

If you are creating these `AccountTeamMember` records via `Apex Trigger`, this is one of the best use cases I have ever found for the `without sharing` keywords (applied in a very targeted manner, of course). When performing administrative tasks triggered by any old end-user, it is an appropriate approach. When I built such functionality, I didn't actually want to enable these users to create an `AccountTeamMember` outside of the circumstances outlined by the trigger.